# how to move files or folders to another folder using sendTo command

Tags: windows-xp, send-to

I'm using Windows 8.

I want to move a file/folders to another folder that I already have in the send To folder but when I right click and send it, it copies it. I was wondering if I could change it to moving it, or copy it then delete all in one step. I am lazy and do not want to send a file then having to delete it myself, that's why I am asking.

Comment: You say that you are using Win-8, and you used Win-XP tag for your question. So which one?

Answer (score 1):

Copying is defined behavior for `Send To...` command, I don't think you can change that. Best solution for your case would be to add `Move To...` command to the context menu. To do that you will need to modify registry entry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

Right Click on it > New Key > Name > Move To > Enter following value:

```
C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13
```

Result should look similar to this

[image]

Also see:

- [Detailed description](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-move-to-copy-to-context-menu)
- [Automated solution](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/516-context-menu-add-copy-folder-move-folder.html)

Comment: I really don't want to edit the regedit if I can. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want without changing the registry. If you don't want to do it manually, I have provided a link to automated solution.